# Are there words for people who are attracted to a specific gender?

Tags: meaning

Is there a word for a person (any male or female) who is attracted to a male?
Is there a word for a person (any male or female) who is attracted to a female?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An *androphilic* individual is attracted to males. A *gynephilic* individual is attracted to females. [image]

Comment: props to tchrist for helping me find this.

Answer (score 3):

*Androsexuals* are attracted to men; *gynosexuals* to women.

Comment: Are you sure those are actual words? I couldn't find them in any dictionary besides Urban dictionary.

Comment: They are equivalent to ‘androphilic’ and ‘gynophilic’, but they are more commonly used when discussing sexual identities than these. ‘Androphilic’ is more commonly used to describe animals (like mosquitos or ticks) that go for humans rather than other species of animals, but that is unrelated to this question.

Comment: Yeah I just found those two terms and posted my own answer before I saw your comment. I understand the validity of your answer now.